# Tomcat 8 + Jersey not showing JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jersey

I'm using Jersey for my REST application. But, one of my methods must return a Viewable that can be a simple HTML file. I have read some tutorials, and finished using an JSP template. 
Everything is working great when I run locally, using Jetty. But, using Tomcat 8, I get the following exception:

> HTTP Status 500 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/confirmacao_jsp, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class objects for the type org/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager used in the signature
>
> type Exception report
>
> message org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader
>   constraint violation: when resolving method
>   "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;"
>   the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader)
>   of the current class, org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/confirmacao_jsp,
>   and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for the
>   method's defining class,
>   org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class
>   objects for the type org/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager used in the
>   signature
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader
>   constraint violation: when resolving method
>   "org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager;"
>   the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader)
>   of the current class, org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/confirmacao_jsp,
>   and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for the
>   method's defining class,
>   org/apache/jasper/runtime/InstanceManagerFactory, have different Class
>   objects for the type org/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager used in the
>   signature

My Servlet configuration is:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>gs.relferreira.corporativo.rest;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>gs.relferreira.corporativo.rest.RelferreiraApplication</param-value>           
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex</param-name>
            <param-value>/resources/(images|css)/. </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

And the method that return a view is the following:

```
@GET
    @Path("confirmar/{idUsuario}/{token}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Viewable validarEmail(@PathParam("idUsuario") int idUsuario, @PathParam("token") String token){      
        if(m_Controlador.validarEmail(idUsuario, token))
            return new Viewable("/confirmacao.jsp", null);
        else 
            return new Viewable("/erro.jsp", null);
    }
```

Comment: did you solved it ?